# App not getting value from edit text, seems to be skipping lines

Tags: java, android

This code does not return a word. It seems that it skips over the "word =" line. et does connect to the correct edit text box. We ran it using debugging, and it went straight to the "try" line, without giving word the value of the et editText box.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_word);

    mydb = new DBHelper(this);

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nw);
    word = et.getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),word,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    l = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ad);
    l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {mydb.insertWord(word);}
            catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            et.setText("");
        }
    });

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {Intent i = new Intent(AddWord.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Check if your editText name is same in xml and class

Answer (score 1):

convert it:

```
l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {mydb.insertWord(word);}
        catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        et.setText("");
    }
```

to:

```
l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {mydb.insertWord(et.getText().toString());}
        catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        et.setText("");
     }
```

and remove this:

```
word = et.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are setting the value of edit-text to word on the very start of activity. Remember that, on start of activity, edit-text is empty and so the word will have empty string. So in order to get the current value in try block, you should again fetch the latest value from edit-text. You can change your try block like this,

```
 try {
        word = et.getText().toString();
        mydb.insertWord(word);
     }
     catch(Exception e){            
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
```